# Making toogle tabs open when clicked on menu, and close when other menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I`ve made this website http://intelmarketing.mk/demos/mediahuset/ and I need help with the menu (toogle tabs).

The idea is when a menu item is clicked the page to scroll down and open the toogle coresponding the menu item. I taught that it can be done with

```
<a href="#link1">Take me to Link 1</a>
<a id="link1">Link 1</a>
```

Made the headers to be images with id's and clicking on the menu scrolls down to the toogle, but not opening.

Also when other menu item is clicked (or tab) the already opened toogle needs to close.

Any help will be welcomed.

Best regards, Nikola.

SITE:
http://intelmarketing.mk/demos/mediahuset/

Update**

The site is build on wordpress platform, and for the toogle tabs I use whistle plugin.
wordpress.org/plugins/whistles/

The menu are simple images.

Comment: you may want to try accordion instead of toggle

Answer (score 0):

On click of "our work" you wish that page should scroll down and a tab should slide down. Presently the page is scrolling down, however tab is not sliding. Am I correct?
You could add two events to your navigation bar tabs 1) to scroll down 2)to slide tab
2nd event is [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) that you're already using

This is not a clean way, but it should work.

Cheers

Comment: The whole deal about it is when clicking on contact on the menu (top right), the page should scroll down on the toogles and open the contact toogle. now just scrolls down but does not open the toogle tab.